# How to access the spreadsheet data for Viewer Node exist in the geometry nodes

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

How to access the Spreadsheet data for Viewer Node created in the Geometry Nodes and how to access the Viewer node value data using blender python-api.[image: Attached Geometry Nodes view screenshot]